# How can I modify a (RecyclerView) viewHolder appearance during runtime?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Say I have a button outside the RecyclerView, that when I press it I want to change the background color of all the items inside the RecyclerView, as well as make some other modifications.

If I have set an onClickListener for this button in the main activity, would I (and if so, how) get a reference to each viewHolder to modify it? And then would I call something like recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the user's screen?

Comment: did you ever listen about `Interfaces` in Java/Android? that 'll do the trick for you. or just make a method in Adapter class .. and call it from main activity with adapter object.

Comment: you will have a reference to recycler or adapter in your main activity. make a method in your adapter and call it from recycler. It will be neat and efficient.

Comment: Hm, when I first tried using recyclerview I tried having methods inside the adapter that were called from a reference to the adapter, and they never worked, I thought I read somewhere that it's not possible.. I'll try it again and see if it works.

But, how do you get a reference to each viewHolder? I can't figure that out.